# php date("d-m-Y") show 11-09-2017 but I need the date without 0 (11-9-2017)

Tags: php

php date("d-m-Y") code show 11-09-2017. I change it to string and need to compare it to other string, 11-9-2017. How can I change the php date("") to return a result with no 0.

for example change:
08-09-2017 -> 8-9-2017

Thank for the answer.

Comment: Use `date("d-n-Y")`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: If you want to compare dates, it's probably easier to use datetime objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong flags to format the date, you need `j` *and* `n` to meet your criteria as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

> j  Day of the month without leading zeros  1 to 31
>
> n  Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through 12

Therefore your code becomes,

```
date("j-n-Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n` in place of `m` `date("d-n-Y");`

Answer (score 0):

```
date("j-n-Y"); to have it without leading zeros day/month
```

Answer (score 0):

User strtotime() function convert dates to time and then compare this two dates. date("j-n-Y"); will also work to get exact date.